# How to solve this issue , flutter build working but android studio not working?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

flutter build run time android mobile it's working but open android studio then generate or run time below function not working

```
List<Disp>.from(
    json["loads"].map((x) => Disp.fromJson(x)));
```

model class Disp

```
    class Disp {
  String dispatch_id;
  String refer_id;
  String trailer_id;
  String trailer_type;

  Disp(this.dispatch_id,
      this.refer_id,
      this.trailer_id,
      this.trailer_type);

  Disp.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : dispatch_id= json['dispatch_id'],
        refer_id= json['refer_id'],
        trailer_id= json['trailer_id'],
        trailer_type= json['trailer_type'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        'dispatch_id' : dispatch_id,
        'refer_id': refer_id,
        'trailer_id': trailer_id,
        'trailer_type':trailer_type,
        
      };
}
```

how to solve this issue? anyone help me. Note : flutter sdk using run build time this function working. but android studio using run or generate apk time this method not working

Comment: {
    "loads": [
        {
            "dispatch_id": "34",
            "refer_id": "R662266",
            "trailer_id": "0",
            "trailer_type": "0"
        } {
            "dispatch_id": "33",
            "refer_id": "R662266dfds",
            "trailer_id": "0",
            "trailer_type": "0"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

From what i see the code is

```
Disp.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : dispatch_id= json['dispatch_id'],
        refer_id= json['refer_id'],
        trailer_id= json['trailer_id'],
        trailer_type= json['trailer_type'];
```

this one should be a factory as below

```
factory Disp.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : dispatch_id= json['dispatch_id'],
        refer_id= json['refer_id'],
        trailer_id= json['trailer_id'],
        trailer_type= json['trailer_type'];
```

I will just add the complete parsing below :

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final disp = dispFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Disp dispFromJson(String str) => Disp.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dispToJson(Disp data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Disp {
    Disp({
        this.loads,
    });

    List<Load> loads;

    factory Disp.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Disp(
        loads: List<Load>.from(json["loads"].map((x) => Load.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "loads": List<dynamic>.from(loads.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Load {
    Load({
        this.dispatchId,
        this.referId,
        this.trailerId,
        this.trailerType,
    });

    String dispatchId;
    String referId;
    String trailerId;
    String trailerType;

    factory Load.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Load(
        dispatchId: json["dispatch_id"],
        referId: json["refer_id"],
        trailerId: json["trailer_id"],
        trailerType: json["trailer_type"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "dispatch_id": dispatchId,
        "refer_id": referId,
        "trailer_id": trailerId,
        "trailer_type": trailerType,
    };
}
```

Use the above json class parser and let me know if it works

```
final disp = dispFromJson(/*your json data string*/);
```